# With whom was Hannah Baker sexting?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In the *13 Reasons Why* episode where Tyler says that Hannah was sexting someone in the court room, they never reveal the name.

Is there any indication who could she be texting to and why?

Comment: Zach? Forgot if they did because Zach wanted it private iirc

Comment: @BCLC Not Zach, she started seeing him later in summer

Comment: Well, some secrets just get buried with the dead, don't they? :)